# Optimal number of column families in HBase and Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra, hbase, bigdata

How Cassandra supports more number of optimal column families when compared to HBase? Any underlying implementation differences?

Comment: it is obviously because the implementation in HBase is faulty - it is a known issue and may be handled with in future versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The HBase Book says](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#number.of.cfs),

> HBase currently does not do well with anything above two or three
>   column families so keep the number of column families in your schema
>   low. Currently, flushing and compactions are done on a per Region
>   basis so if one column family is carrying the bulk of the data
>   bringing on flushes, the adjacent families will also be flushed though
>   the amount of data they carry is small.

Cassandra flushes per-columnfamily, per replica.  How it determines when to flush each when there are dozens or hundreds of CFs is touched on [in this post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-1-0-improved-memory-and-disk-space-management).